# C++11 - Unicode string - find if contains non-ascii based characters

Tags: c++11, unicode, utf-8

I have Unicode string in C++11 represented in UTF8 class. I can get Unicode character numbers. How can I check, if the string contains characters, that are not ASCII based (with diacritics)?

Eg. I want to detect Japanese, Arabic, Russian etc., but for special characters like German `ü`, Czech `č`, French `î` etc. I want to said, that it is "ASCII like"

(I dont want to use Boost)

Comment: In UTF-8 each character is encoded by one or more 8-bit bytes. The plain ASCII characters are encoded using only 7 of those 8 bits, which means you can easily recognize them as their highest bit will always be zero. That should be pretty clear if you [read *anything* about UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes.. I will recongize ASCII only, but non ASCII derived with diacritics.

Comment: This question conflates a few concepts. There's ASCII, there's Latin script, and there are diacritics. The Dutch Ĳ (U+00132) is Latin, not-ASCII and does not contain a diacritic. Is it ASCII-like? Arguably yes, since it decomposes to I J. See also æ and ß. On the flip side, non-Latin scripts can also contain diacritics. This happens in the related Cyrillic and Greek scripts, but also in Thai IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, using [unicode string normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) with use of [Unilib](https://github.com/ufal/unilib).

I am iterating string char by char. My UTF8 string is represented with [TinyUTF8](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tiny-utf8/) library (which is now maintained on [github](http://github.com/DuffsDevice/tinyutf8)).

```
utf8_string u8str = u8"\u4e0a\u6d77 Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy";

for (auto c : u8str){
    std::u32string uu;
    uu.push_back(c);        
    ufal::unilib::uninorms::nfd(uu);

    if (uu[0] < 128){
       //has ASCII base
    }
}
```